# JQuery TouchTouch plugin doesn't display photos if their URLs were dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have a JQuery TouchTouch based gallery on one of my websites. It works perfect when I call it once for the photos list that was loaded with the page. Recently, I needed to add new functionality to this page (the website is online store, I'm talking about page with a product). I need to load same product of a different color without leaving the page (different URLs are still used for this purpose, but I need to change this ASAP because of duplicates affect SEO).

Using AJAX, I'm loading all necessary information about product (including photos URLs) and everything is ok, except the JQTT gallery: if I don't call *touchTouch()* on selector that was used the first time, during the page loading - nothing works at all (that is obviously, because no photos information auto-updates provided in plugin). However, when I call *touchTouch()* second time on the same selector, overlay with buttons (arrows) appears, but photo **is never loaded, only the loading GIF is shown permanently**. I have checked this in Mozilla FireFox and Google Chrome - the same behavior. By the way, thumbnail photos are loaded fine, but displaying them is not directly related to the plugin, because they are only triggers for loading large photos.

The first thing that may help, as I supposed, **was a test**: call *touchTouch()* not immediately after AJAX-request and new photos insertion in DOM, but call it after a long delay (for example, 10 secs) to make sure that problem is not in plugin's preloading features (if any) or someting similar. That didn't help.

Then I made the **second test**: I deleted first *touchTouch()* call in document-ready (so, plugin doesn't work on document load), then made this call after updating photos. **In this case, plugin worked fine.**

So, in view of the aforesaid, **i'm searching for solution how to make JQTT plugin work after photos list update**. The selector is always the same (I mean CSS class name that is used for every photo and that is called in *$(selector).touchTouch()*).

---

Here is a real example on website: http://raroom.com/chairs/chair_bertoia/bertoia-1
At the moment, two versions of one product (designer's chair with black seat and with white seat) is available via two links (current is marked with thick black underscore). Second link ends with "bertoia-2" (instead of "bertoia-1").

I writed a function loadProductPage(productId) to load the second product without following a link (you can see code in the bottom of page source). If you call this function from console - you will see the problem described (id of second product in DB is 6, for first is 5, so, if you open first link - call *loadProductPage(6)*).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so pitty, 5 days left and nobody helped me with such an easy question. I found a solution by myself. Having no other choice, rather then to explore the JQuery Touch Touch JS code line by line, I noticed that it creates new div's with class "placeholder" inside the div with id "galleryOverlay", no matter if they were creater earlier or not. I mean, it appends new placeholder-divs to existing ones (at the previous call of *touchTouch()* method), so it breaks the script logic and it cannot load new photos anymore, because of using wrong placeholder-divs.

The solution is to delete previous placeholder-divs before updating photos and thumbnails URL's and before calling *touchTouch()* method again. With JQuery it is one simple line of code:

```
$('#gallerySlider .placeholder').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you, this post saved me a lot of trouble :)